# pandas set_option max_colwidth not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1)
pd.DataFrame({1: ['1' * 1000] * 10000000})
```

When run in a jupyter notebook it still displays all the character in the row. I want the 1's to be truncated, but it isn't working no matter how hard I try. This is very frustrating, how can this be fixed?

Edit: Doesn't work with any number or setting

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 5)
pd.set_option('max_seq_items', 5)
pd.DataFrame({1: ['1' * 1000] * 10000000})
```

Comment: It's gotta be `>=3` for the `...`.

Comment: @QuangHoang nope, still not working even with this new code `import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 5)
pd.set_option('max_seq_items', 5)
pd.DataFrame({1: ['1' * 1000] * 10000000})`

Comment: I just tested and it needs to be `>=4` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do the following and never had any issue.

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = X
```

Also just tested the number needs to be at least `4` to work properly.

I'm using pandas 1.4.3 btw.

[image]

Comment: I updated the post, still isn't working

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch What version of pandas are you using.

Comment: pandas I'm using version 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me if I want to display max_colwidth (min is 4) and max_rows = 5 in jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 4, "display.max_rows", 5)
pd.DataFrame({1: ['1' * 1000] * 10000000})
```

[image]

Comment: what version of pandas and jupyter are you using?